# Creating a list of URL's

Tags: java, android, eclipse, url-routing

I have a app with a list of urls, I can create a class that will link to the urls and open the link within the browser, trouble is I have more than 100 urls and I dont think it would be practical to create a class for each of those urls.  So I want to create a class that will get the correct url based on the users selection from a list.  I have 92 chioces with 4 or 5 links attached to each, which is the best way to do this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I must be misunderstanding what your question is. If you just want to display a list of URLs, just make a String array of URLs, and adapt that to a ListView. You say you have 4 or 5 links attached to each choice though, which is where I'm confused. Are you wanting to open multiple windows in the browser?

Comment: I have 4 tabbed list views when u select 1 of these choices in list it opens another list with 6 functions 1 of them is url links to forums, at the moment I have each link  in a separate class but I have realised I need to create a class that will identify the link needed and display it in a browser, if keep opening urls in their own class I will.have 460 classes for the url function alone I want just one class to deal with getting the url and one class to display it.